# Personal log of peer review conducted at Elsevier journals

Tags: peer-review, bibliometrics, elsevier

A few months ago, I found a web app that showed statistics on my experience as a reviewer, especially with respect to Elsevier journals; it just displayed the number of referee reports I had submitted, for each journal.

Given the data, I think it was some service owned by Elsevier, but despite my best efforts, I cannot find it anymore. I thought it might have been Mendeley, but not quite: my (private) Mendeley profile just shows the last two papers I've reviewed, along with a broken link to "view all publications".

Publons, in principle, is similar to what I'm looking for, but it does not have any agreement with Elsevier (and in fact, the peer review part of my Publons profile is currently empty).
Any ideas?

Comment: Checked your browser history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Elsevier's [Reviewer Recognition](https://www.reviewerrecognition.elsevier.com) site/platform. According to a description [here](https://www.elsevier.com/editors-update/story/peer-review/reviewer-recognition-platform) this platform lets reviewers track their reviews, claim book discounts, etc. [It also mentions a service for public reviewer pages (hmm, where have I heard about that before?), but the provided link is broken so I'm not sure if that's still available or not.]

Comment: That's it, thank you! I guess one of the reasons why it was so hard for me to find it again is that profile pages are "public" but not tracked; that is, instead of being able to access your information using your Elsevier password, you need to ask that a link to your profile (shareable? I guess you shouldn't) is sent to you via email. I wonder why